# How to force creation of manifest file in release folder?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, regfreecom

This is driving me crazy. I have developed a .NET COM DLL that is used by a VB6 DLL wrapper in order to update and replace some legacy functions in an application.

I am now trying to remove the requirement to use regasm on client machines so have worked out how to do that on a test DLL which all works fine.

I branched the DLL just in case and added an app.manifest file. Everything else worked out fine and I got it all working. The manifest is embedded and Visual Studio 2012 generates a mydll.dll.manifest file in the release folder.

Then I went back to the original trunk and added an app.manifest file (no point in merging as there were no code changes). I copied the contents of the branch into the app.manifest file and built the release version. The manifest is embedded in the DLL but no mydll.dll.manifest file is generated.

I know that it's not strictly necessary to have the mydll.dll.manifest file but I'd like things to be consistent (and for some reason the test process doesn't produce the same results with the trunk version) so how can I force it to be created?

This is a VB.NET DLL project so it doesn't have (or I can't find) the 'Generate Manifest' property drop down mentioned in the [first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631081/building-release-version-of-a-c-sharp-application). How can I set this? Or is there a way to set it by editing the project file directly?

References:

- [Original walkthrough article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) and [some corrections](http://jwbs-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/registration-free-com-components_16.html).
- [Overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/04/20/579748.aspx) by Junfeng Zhang in [two articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/05/17/595140.aspx) plus a [useful tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2007/04/14/genman32-a-tool-to-generate-sxs-manifest-for-managed-assembly-for-registration-free-com-net-interop.aspx)

Comment: You don't need a manifest for a dll because it uses the security token of the current process e.g. the application, so you need the manifest for your exe (I think)

Comment: Yes I know that but the manifest also needs to be embedded for the reg free com to work

Answer (score 2):

You are making a fairly common mistake.  A reg-free COM manifest helps an application find a COM server without looking in the registry to locate the DLL.  Embedding the manifest in the DLL is like trying to solve the chicken and egg problem, Windows cannot possibly find that manifest if it cannot locate the DLL first.

The manifest needs to be part of the client app.  Which is tricky since it is VB6, it doesn't support embedding manifests in its executables.

You could tinker with the mt.exe tool, an SDK utility that supports embedding manifests in an executable.  You'd have to run it by hand after building the VB6 binaries.  That's unfun and very likely to cause trouble when you forget.  It is in general not a joyful tool to use, documentation is meager, incomplete and unhelpful, a chronic problem with manifests.

The fall back is a separate app.exe.manifest file, what Windows will look for next when it cannot find a manifest embedded in the executable.  Where "app.exe" must be renamed to the name of the VB6 program.  The EXE, not the DLL.  This now also gives you a chance to avoid having to register the VB6 DLL, presumably what you really want if you truly want to make your program run reg-free.  The disadvantage is that it will not work when you debug your VB6 program, wrong EXE.  You'd also need a vb6.exe.manifest, located in the VB6 install directory.

Needless to say perhaps, very hard to get ahead with VB6 here.  It just wasn't made to help you do this, they didn't have a time machine in 1998.

Comment: The, admittedly out of date, walkthrough here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx adds a manifest to the library as well as the client, are you saying that it is not necessary to use a library manifest to get reg free com working? If so please point me in the direction of a correct reference

Comment: That question never talks about a DLL.  Nor does it have anything to do with a reg-free COM manifest.  Manifests are used for more than one reason.  A C# EXE always has a manifest, even if you don't explicitly add one, it declares the EXE compatible with UAC.

Comment: I cut and pasted the wrong link the first time, please check the correct msdn one which I've since edited in

Comment: I don't know why you are giving me these links, I already know how manifests work.  You won't get ahead until *you* understand how they work.  The chicken-and-egg problem is clearly your biggest hangup, don't add the manifest to *your* DLL, it needs to go into the executable that **uses** the DLL.

Comment: Why do all the examples add a manifest to the library? It's all very well saying bluntly that I don't understand but you're not providing any means for me to get to a point where I can understand and what you say flatly contradicts others statements

Comment: Quote from the first link: `create an application manifest file (a text file) for the client.exe application`.  Quote from the second link: `For example, the application manifest file name for myComApp.exe is myComApp.exe.manifest.`  I fail to see why you think these articles tell you to embed the manifest in a DLL, they clearly talk about embedding it in the EXE.  I don't think I can help you read these MSDN pages better, sorry.  I understand your dislike of having to make a VB6 program work with it, there's however nothing I can do to make you feel better about that.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit that I don't know VB at all, but in the case of C++ and C# Visual Studio projects I previously had to resort to calling mt.exe in a post-build step in order to get the DLL manifest I wanted. Maybe that workaround would work in your case as well?